# How to check a time variable is greater than 1 hour?

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, constraints

I have an issue that has to check a time variable is greater than 1 hour. Help me!
This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE
(
    MovieID int identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    MovieName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Duration time check(HOURS(Duration) >= 1) NOT NULL,
    Genre int check(Genre between 1 and 8) NOT NULL,
    Direction varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    [Money] money NOT NULL,
    Comments varchar(100),
)
```

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server)?  "SQL" is just a language.

Comment: I am using SQL SERVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check a time variable like this way

```
check(DATEPART(HOUR, Duration) >= 1)
```

Comment: No problem. [Here's the documentation, for future reference.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017)